# How to exclude the first trees in predict.ranger?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

In the documentation of ranger package (Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ranger/ranger.pdf), for the function predict.ranger(),one can set num.trees,which is

> Number of trees used for prediction. The first num.trees in the forest are used.

How can i set the num.trees so that the prediction process does not use the first few trees? I think the first few trees in the forest are less accurate, so i would like to ignore them in the prediction part.

Comment: When quoting from a source, please also include the relevant link - especially if the source is available online. Please edit & update your post accordingly.

Comment: FWIW, the trees in any RF implementation are fiitted independently, so the situation you describe is rather (highly) unlikely.

Comment: In boosting algorithms you expect the weak learners to get better. But Random Forest is not boosted. Your expectation should be that any tree is as good as any other tree, the order in which they were fit doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder and thank you guys for clarification!